# Magento 2: Add multiple products to cart programmatically does not work if cart is empty!

Tags: magento2, module, cart, extensions, addtocart

I have the same problem as mentioned in this Question: [Magento 2: Add multiple products to cart programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196766/magento-2-add-multiple-products-to-cart-programmatically) But it was never answered. This is my Controller.php:

```
<?php

namespace MassiveArt\ShoppingCart\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var FormKey
     */
    protected $formKey;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param FormKey $formKey
     * @param Cart $cart
     * @param Product $product
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        FormKey $formKey,
        Cart $cart,
        Product $product
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        try {

            // Set result data and pass back
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

            if(!$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId()) {
                $result->setData(['error' => __('Invalid session ID')]);
            }


            // Get parameters
            $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productIds');
            $amounts = $this->getRequest()->getParam('amounts');

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($productIds); $i++) {// Load product by ID
                $product = $this->product->load($productIds[$i]);
                // New product params
                $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productIds[$i],
                    'qty'   => $amounts[$i],
                );


                // Save Product
                $product->save();

                // Add product to cart
                $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            }

            //Save cart
            $this->cart->save();

            $result->setData(['message' => __("Products added succesfully")]);

            return $result;
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $result->setData(['error' => __($e->getMessage())]);
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

**The code works fine, if the cart is not empty**, but if the cart is empty only one product is added to cart with sum of quantity for all the product.

**For eg if I add: Prod 1 - 2 quantity Prod 2 - 1 quantity
Cart will contain prod 1 with 3 quantity.**

Please let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a non-injectable object `Product $product` to fetch the product object and it might cause issue sometimes. Instead, we should use ProductFactory

Can you try the following snippet?

```
<?php

namespace MassiveArt\ShoppingCart\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var FormKey
     */
    protected $formKey;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * @var ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param Context                         $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param JsonFactory                     $resultJsonFactory
     * @param FormKey                         $formKey
     * @param Cart                            $cart
     * @param ProductFactory                  $productFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        FormKey $formKey,
        Cart $cart,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try {

            // Set result data and pass back
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

            if (!$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId()) {
                $result->setData(['error' => __('Invalid session ID')]);
            }

            // Get parameters
            $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productIds');
            $amounts = $this->getRequest()->getParam('amounts');

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($productIds); $i++) {// Load product by ID
                $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productIds[$i]);
                // New product params
                $params = [
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product'  => $productIds[$i],
                    'qty'      => $amounts[$i],
                ];

                // Save Product
                $product->save();

                // Add product to cart
                $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            }

            //Save cart
            $this->cart->save();

            $result->setData(['message' => __("Products added succesfully")]);

            return $result;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result->setData(['error' => __($e->getMessage())]);
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i copy your snippet i get a internal server error, does not seem to be working properly. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Did you remove the generated folder and flush the cache? What is the message in the log?

Comment: As i said I get an internal server error and not more. will try to flush the cache and remove the general folder

Comment: The internal error is a server error. Maybe something is wrong with the snippet since I didn't test it. Can you enable the logging report and then send me the error message?

Comment: Thank you very much, after flushing cache everything works. You are the best.